# Javascript CSS with automatic Multiple Columns Display for contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tried for a week, and still not work.

Here is the demo:

https://myspace.com/discover/trending/2014/01/03/artist-of-the-day-the-jazmin-sisters-are-sonic-siblings/

For example, if you resize the browser and change "height", the number of columns auto increase by the "height" while the "width" is keeping same.

Any one can help me? I am using bootstrap 3, but the problem is the content can't move from column to column to increase the number of columns automatic. My site is a slide like myspace, with touch screen move from left to right.

**** I need to find a way automatic split the contents to multiple columns, with number of columns base on the height value of browser.

For example:

```
<div id="contaner">
   <h3>Title 1</h3>
   <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
   <p>Content Here</p>

 <h3>Title 1</h3>
   <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
   <p>Content Here</p>

 <h3>Title 1</h3>
   <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
   <p>Content Here</p>


 <h3>Title 1</h3>
   <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
  <p>Content Here</p>
   <p>Content Here</p>
</div>
```

If the browser have enought height for it, it will display as 1 column, but if the browser have smaller height by resize, it auto split to 2, 3 columns, etc ...
The width of column I can set by my own, like 300px...

I don't know how to do it :( Any suggestion or recommended? Thanks bros.

Comment: your code is quite big, cant you be a little more specific and provide and example of code

Comment: Right now, I am using bootstrap to store columns as CSS. But I need find a way to split the contents to multiple columns with the number of columns calculated automatic by the height value of browser.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works on width columns.. but I guess you could alter the height with a **@viewport** and **@media** on your CSS.

I've never heard of what you are trying but IMO you don't need to scale by height.